# How to prevent Silverlight Webbrowser Control to open links in new windows?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Silverlight 5 application which shows a Dynamics CRM 2013 webpage (list of accounts) in a Silverlight webbrowser control. When the user clicks on one entity record in the list the detail view of that record should open in the same browser. It is opened in a new browser window instead. How can I make the Silverlight webbrowser open it in the same window? In a standard Internet Explorer it is opened in the same browser window.

I found a [solution](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/10/17/browser-control-prevent-a-link-to-open-in-a-new-page/) how to achieve that in a .Net webbrowser control. However this is different from the Silverlight webbrowser control I have. Especially the "Document" property and the events "DocumentCompleted" and "NewWindow" are missing.

I use Internet Explorer 11 on a Windows 7 machine to test it. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Arne

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("the address here"), "_self");
```

The key is the second parameter "_self", which means that you want to open the link on the same page. You can also use "_blank" for new tab or "_top" to put it on top of the hierarchy.

Useful links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189809(v=vs.95).aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not call the navigate function, but the user clicks on a link inside the page and the browser opens a new window then. My question is, how to make the browser open the link the user clicked on in the same browser window. the solution you proposed could work, if I could catch the click and call the navigate method in some event handler. Unfortunately, I do not know how to catch the click in the Silverlight version of the webbrowser.